# How to force play framework to log exceptions which are thrown in another thread?

Tags: exception, logging, playframework, future

I have a function which is running in the separate thread. The code which calls this function not waits for result of it.

```
def sendEmail(email: String): Future[Unit] = {
  ...
}

def registration: Future[User] = {
   ...
   // I do not want to wait for result of this function, just fire email sending
   // in seprate thread and continue
   sendEmail(email)
   ...
   // Do another job
}
```

The problem is that if something went wrong in `sendEmail` function, I want to see this exception in log file.
Now log file and console output are empty if some exception is thrown there.

Is there a way to log exceptions from that separate thread?

P.S.: I do not want to log exception manually in `sendEmail`, but force play framework to log it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you wrap exceptions in the exceptionally block.
In java, it's like :

```
foobar.thenComposeAsync(arg -> {
   sendEmail();
}).exceptionally(throwable -> {
   // Do logging
});
```